# Why am I getting "Command Failed" error after debug with buildozer?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, apk, buildozer

I am trying to make an apk file from a kivy based .py file with buildozer on Ubuntu in Windows;
after I ran "sudo buildozer android debug" after a while i get below error message

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "__main__", mod_spec)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1196, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                         main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main                                                                                                                                                                                                             ToolchainCL()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 671, in __init__                                                                                                                                                                                                          getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 148, in wrapper_func                                                                                                                                                                                                      user_ndk_api=self.ndk_api)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 296, in prepare_build_environment                                                                                                                                                                                             apis = get_available_apis(self.sdk_dir)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 75, in get_available_apis                                                                                                                                                                                                     targets = get_targets(sdk_dir)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 62, in get_targets                                                                                                                                                                                                            avdmanager = sh.Command(join(sdk_dir, 'tools', 'bin', 'avdmanager'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 1202, in __init__                                                                                                                                                                                                                               raise CommandNotFound(path)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              sh.CommandNotFound: /home/lunedor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager   
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=RandomMovie --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/c/RMA/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     HOME = '/home/lunedor'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     PATH = '/home/lunedor/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     USER = 'root'
#     USERNAME = 'root'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer android debug deploy run'
#     SUDO_USER = 'lunedor'
#     SUDO_UID = '1000'
#     SUDO_GID = '1000'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/lunedor/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/lunedor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/lunedor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2issue with buildozer itself.
```

Comment: There is no error in your output, but there is: `The error might be hidden in the log above this error`, in order to help you , more logs are needed !

Comment: At first don't start buildozer with sudo. Just type 'buildozer android debug'. At second try to download Python-for-android by yourself and write down the path of it in the spec file. I'd recommend to do that with NDK, SDK and SDK tools also, but at first start with python-for-android.

Comment: @user801247 i alreday make "log_level = 2" in spec file, that could be just a warning maybe?

Comment: @Lothric I tried  'buildozer android debug' too but same error, now I will try to download python-for-android etc manually then try again

Comment: @Lunedor it's not my opinion, it's written in the docs not to launch buildozer with sudo :)

Comment: Yes I saw that :) when i got an error and research for solutions but can't get not much then i try everything which come to my mind, specially sudo for linux :) also i added first line before error, it seems related python-for-android and i install again but same error. I am working on a virtual machine and my folder is in my "c:" directory, that can cause a problem? i can't figure out how i can mout an entire folder to ubuntu vm..

Comment: @Lunedor what? Your files are in Windows? Enable drag-n-drop and put it into Ubuntu.

Comment: @Lothric Yes they are in windows directory but i am getting there by cd then trying to apply things, that doesn't feel good to me at start but after getting there I think that can work but this error can be related with that. And drag-n-drop only get the file directory name in terminal which is only i have in windows right now. Maybe I should mount a directory somehow, actually mnt means that i thought..

Comment: @Lunedor upload your files somewhere and download it in Ubuntu. And try 'buildozer android update' and then 'buildozer android debug'

Comment: tried that too but same error, i tried to make my file work on virtual machine and get an error such as "Couldn't connect to X server " that may be cause the problem, I will try virtual box instead of ubuntu on windows store..

Comment: I downloaded and setup a debian on virtualbox, copy my file to there, install all necessary things, get an error then search for solution, handle it and get another error then find a solution from google then get another one, last one was(comman failed: usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandorid.toolchain create dist_name=......) :) so any other way to make an apk for kivy, python apps except buildozer?